# What is milk product in cocoa butter?

Tags: butter, cocoa

What does "may contain milk" mean on the side of my cocoa butter container? Is it not pure cocoa butter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Callebaut's cocoa butter callets, "may contain milk", melts strangely](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55510/callebauts-cocoa-butter-callets-may-contain-milk-melts-strangely)

Comment: @ChingChong I would prefer to close the other question. This one at least has an answer and is more to the point.

Comment: I agree with ChrisSteinbach and it appears that this question was a new user attempting to post an improved version of the other with good intent. lb: In the future just edit the original, SE sites have a slightly different etiquette than the usual forums.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbach I agree with you, too. I just wasn't sure about whether to mark the newer (but better) question or the other question as the duplicate :-\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any time you see something like "may contain" after an ingredient list, it's a warning that it might contain trace amounts of that substance and so could be harmful to anyone who's allergic to it. Basically what they're saying is that they didn't intentionally add any milk or milk products to the cocoa butter, but since they make other products at the same factory that use milk they can't guarantee that some hasn't slipped in somehow.

So assuming that cocoa butter is the only ingredient then it would be pure cocoa butter, at least by the legal definition.

Comment: Thank you for your all your help with my question, I don't think I belong in this forum, so I better get out now while the going is good, sorry for any mis spellings. Thanks again.

Comment: @lb While you're not going to be able to ask many question related to your cosmetic business here, I don't think there's an issue with you not "belonging" here. Your first question wasn't phrased very well, but it wasn't so much a problem with spelling as it didn't immediately seem to be on topic. Plenty of people are willing to help you out with spelling and grammar, but Stack Exchange sites in general can bit quick on the gun when it comes to questions that appear to be off-topic.

Comment: Well this is how we learn. I am asking a question with all do respect, when you say, "didn't immediately seem to be on topic" do you mean I should have just wrote. Cocoa Butter callets, what does "may contain milk " mean and left it at that?

Comment: @lb There's nothing wrong with how you phrased your second question, it clear and concise. If it were how you phrased your first question everything would be fine. The only problem with your second question is that it duplicates the first. Note that your first question actually asks two questions, one about milk and one about melting. You might want to edit your first question so it only asks about the problem with melting, that way you're asking two different questions in two separate posts. You should also add more details about what you did to melt it and what it ended up like.

Comment: @lb Ross Ridge is correct. We function somewhat differently from a forum, and many people have a hard time following the rules from the beginning, because they are not aware that they exist. But we don't bear grudges against people, even if we have downvoted or closed a question which does not fit our format. You are free to go or stay, but if you decide to stay, we have a help section which can make it easier, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help. Also, I'm glad you could get a good answer to this one question, even if the process was a bit hard.